# What's the best practice to send out bulk emails in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm expecting about 200 - 400 emails to be sent every 2 - 3 weeks in one go. This is based on the event and the event being a `project` published on the website. So once it is published, an automatic email goes out to all the subscribers. I'm using `Laravel 5.3` and the new `notifications API`.

So the code at the moment simply looks like this

```
$subscribers->each(function($subscriber) use($project) {
   $subscriber->notify(new ProjectPublished($project));
});
```

Would it make sense to implement `ShouldQueue` in this scenario?

Comment: You may just end up shifting the responsibility for throttling email sends to the queue workers. Aren't you using an email provider who will manage that for you?

Comment: I'm using Sendgrid. But I thought I still needed to queue stuff even in that case?

Comment: If the project being published as a result of a user request and you don't want to prevent that request from completing until 400 emails are sent you use shouldQueue and add queue workers. If the project is published automatically (a Command maybe), you can decide whether to run that for the time it should take to send the emails directly to SendGrid, or to use shouldQueue and add a worker. Probably tidier all round to queue them and use workers, but if you don't want to implement the queueing system merely for this and are not keeping a user waiting, it's not a necessity.